# limit foreignkey's field choices in django admin

Tags: django, django-admin

I have 4 simple model :

model.py

```py
class State(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)

class County(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    state = models.ForeignKey(State, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

class District(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30,null=True, blank=True)
    county = models.ForeignKey(County,on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)

class Teacher(model.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    state = models.ForeignKey(State, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    county = models.ForeignKey(County,on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
    district = models.ForeignKey(District,on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
```

admin.py:

```
@admin.register(Teacher)
class TeacherAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ['name','state','county','district']
```

my issue is in `Teacher` admin page  for field `county` and `district` all the county and district display in drop down select box. what i want is just county and district of teacher's state display . thank you

Answer (score 0):

Default of these fields are select to make you change the field in the admin page.Anyway if you want to have only the value you can use below code.

Add the below code to your model class in `models.py` file:

```
def state_value(self):
  return ("%s" % (self.state.name))
```

And your `admin.py` file will be like:

```
@admin.register(Teacher)
class TeacherAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
  list_display = ['name','state_value']
```

And you can repeat this process for other fields too.

Comment: thanks for reply , i don't want show name of state of district or county instead of drop down list. i want in "district" field just that districts are belong to "state" show up . for example `teacher.state` is Tehran and want to display just "district"'s of Tehran in district's drop down in teacher's admin page.

Comment: the real problem is as  now i have 5000 of District's model instance and about 1500 County's  model instance so when i want edit teachers's district ,all that 5000 district will display in drop down in admin page! but i just want change district between district that belong to state .